# React rendering an empty page after an Express API call

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I am new to React and after peforming a post request with Express my localhost page goes blank, rendering a sort of default HTML blank document. but the call works properly, saving the new document in my DB. Here's my React Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  getTasks,
  addTask,
  updateTask,
  deleteById
} from '../services/api'

class Tasks extends Component {
  state = { tasks: [], currentTask:"" }

  async componentDidMount(){
    try {
      const {data} = await getTasks();
      this.setState({tasks:data});
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  handleChange = ({currentTarget: input}) => {
    this.setState({currentTask: input.value});
  }

  handleSubmit =(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const existingTasks = this.state.tasks;
    try {
      const {data} = addTask({task: this.state.currentTask});
      const tasks = existingTasks;
      tasks.push(data);
      this.setState({tasks, currentTask:""});
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  handleUpdate = (currentTask) => {
    const existingTasks = this.state.tasks;
    try {
      const tasks = [...existingTasks];
      const idx = tasks.findIndex((task) => task._id === currentTask);
      tasks[idx] = {...tasks[idx]};
      tasks[idx].state = 1;
      this.setState({tasks});
      updateTask(currentTask);
    } catch(err) {
      this.setState({tasks: existingTasks});
    }
  }

  handleDelete = async(currentTask) => {
    const existingTasks = this.state.tasks;
    try {
      const tasks = existingTasks.filter(task => task._id !== currentTask);
      this.setState({tasks});
      await deleteById(currentTask)
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({tasks: existingTasks});
    }
  }
}

export default Tasks;
```

My App.js

```
import Tasks from './components/Tasks';
import './assets/App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Paper, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Checkbox, Button} from '@material-ui/core';
import './assets/App.css';

class App extends Tasks{
  state = { tasks: [], currentTask: '' }
  render(){
    const {tasks} = this.state;
    return(
      <div className='App flex'>
        <Paper elevation={3} className='container'>
          <div className='header'>
            TO-DO
          </div>
          <form className='flex margin' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <TextField variant='outlined' size='small' style={{width: "80%"}} required={true} placeholder="Next thing to do... ️"
            value={this.state.currentTask}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <Button 
            style={{height: "40px"}} color='primary' variant='outlined' type='submit'>
              Add task
            </Button>
            <div>
              {tasks.map((task) => (
                <Paper key={task._id} className='flex task-container'>
                  <Checkbox color='primary'
                  checked={task.state}
                  onClick={() => this.handleUpdate(task._id)}/>
                  <div className={task.state ? 'task_line_through' : 'task'}>{task.name}</div>
                  <Button
                  onClick={() => this.handleDelete(task._id)}>
                    Delete
                  </Button>
                </Paper>
              ))}
            </div>
          </form>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

My services calling my APIs from the BE:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const PATH = '/api/tasks';

const getTasks = () => axios.get(PATH);
const addTask = name => axios.post(PATH, name);
const updateTask = id => axios.patch(`${PATH}/${id}`);
const deleteById = id => axios.delete(`${PATH}/${id}`);

export {
  getTasks,
  addTask,
  updateTask,
  deleteById
}
```

The API that triggers the blank page rendering and the one showing the elements

```
router.route("/").post((req, res) => {
  console.log('Create');
  const taskName = req.body.task;
  console.log(req.body);
  const task = new Task({ name: taskName, state: 0 });
  task.save()
    .then(data => { res.status(200).json(data) })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json("Error" + err));
});

//READ
router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  console.log('Read');
  Task.find({ state: 0 })
  .then(data => { res.status(200).json(data) })
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json("Error" + err));
});
```

My server:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
const routes = require("./routes/loadRoutes")
let v8 = require("v8");
let totalHeapSizeInGB = (((v8.getHeapStatistics().total_available_size) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2));

console.log(`*******************************************`);
console.log(`Total Heap Size ~${totalHeapSizeInGB}GB`);
console.log(`*******************************************`);

require('log-timestamp');
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
  
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

//PREFLIGHT REQUEST
app.options('*', cors())

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error connecting to DB...");
        console.log(err)
    }
});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
    console.log("DB connection made ...");
})

routes.loadRoutes(app)

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server running... on port: ' + port);
})
```

In my package.json of the client I added this to make react routing with node: "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"

When I make the call there's rendered one root  with this comment:

```
  This HTML file is a template.
  If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

  You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
  The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

  To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
  To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
-->
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help, I'm super stuck with it.

Comment: Why are you using both `await` and Promises in your Router APi ? Any one can be used, not both simultaneously

Comment: You're right, I've been trying to do a lot of changes in order to get a solution for my problem and forgot to fix it back, i just did it deleting the try blocks. Do you have any clue about the issue of the rendering? @ShubhankarKG

Comment: Your client side rendering issue maybe due to your Router not being implemented properly. Please fix the router first, and then update the question and the code as well.

Comment: I just did but it keeps showing me the blank page. I edited my Tasks.js here too

Comment: You are getting it wrong, your problem is here: `router.route("/").post(async(req, res) => {...` This is what you need to fix, the client side was okay as it was before

Comment: Ok, I just updated this and reverted the changes in Tasks.js. I also added the route to show all the tasks

Comment: Can you do a conditional render? show the tasks div only if the tasks has a valid Array? The code set looks good IMHO

Comment: That was the problem! I was not checking if there were tasks in the array and by the time the useState was triggered the new task was not yet available for React to render it. I solved it making it async, i'll post the code in a moment. Thanks a lot!!